# PHP GD library not working on Ubuntu

Tags: php, apache, gd, lamp

I installed PHP GD via *aptitude* and it's showing as installed there. but *phpinfo* doesn't show it.

This is the error which I can see when I executed `php -m` from command prompt:

> PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php5/20090626+lfs/gd.so' - /usr/lib/php5/20090626+lfs/gd.so: undefined symbol: gdImageCreateFromJpeg in Unknown on line 0

I've tried reinstalling, restarting, etc, but of no use...

Answer (score 0):

On the GD website it says:

> If you get undefined symbol errors, be
>   sure to check for older versions of
>   libpng in your library directories!

See http://www.boutell.com/gd/manual2.0.1.html

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had the old version of `libgd.so` in `/usr/local/lib/` which was picked first in path. Renaming the directory to something else forced PHP to look for the file further and found the correct file in `/usr/lib/`. Linking to `libgd.so` to the right version should help too.